# I'm having some problem in focusing buttons

Tags: html, web, button, focus

I'm having some problem with some button focus effects, although, I don't know if I'm supposed to use focus or not. So yesterday, I was trying to make a coffee roasters website. Now I have to create some options

eg.
What type of coffee the user wants and how much etc.

So for that. I made h1s and below that I made some buttons. If they click on a button, It should change it's appearance so that the user knows it's selected now, when I am clicking on another button from another category, the previous category button is getting deselected because I used focus.

I want all my categories to have different options and that the user can select any one option from a particular category but in terms of categories they can select a button from each category without deselecting the previous button from the previous category.

I hope I didn't complicate the question but how can I do that?

Please help me somebody!

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont want to use a focus in your case, since it just inidcates the currently active buttone, so the user knows which one is active, for example if he wants to use the space key to press it multiple times or when he just navigates whith tabs / only the keyboard.

What you want is to change the whole buttons aperance and this you have to accomplish trough css and some programming language like javaScript.
You can write a function, which checks wich button of some category is selected (use radio buttons, if you just want to allow one to be selected at a time)
and changes the button to a different style until the user selects another button on this category.

It seems a bit more complicated, than just using a focus, so if you have not much experience with HTML and especilly not with CSS and javaScript, I suggest, you first try to learn a bit about these topics and go trough some tutorials online.